# SEO: Marking up content to have Google produce breadcrumb links when used in search results

Tags: html, xhtml, seo, metadata

Some Google search results have special "navigation" items right underneath their descriptions. Sometimes it even separates the query string from the URI and puts (an) arrow(s) in between. I'm sure you've all stumbled upon that some time.

Here's a picture so you get an idea of what I'm talking about:

[image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/8719ecbddc137b1751b3129392d32124.png))</sub>

Now my question:

Is there anything in terms of coding/markup one has to do to get Google to display one's search result like that? I'm already using pretty URLs by the way.

Note: I'm currently working on a website and it isn't online yet - I just want to make sure I do as many things as possible the right way.

Comment: Closed as cross-site dupe: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/443/how-do-i-get-google-to-show-links-to-my-site-hierarchy-in-search-results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> At the moment, sitelinks are completely automated. We're always working to improve our sitelinks algorithms, and we may incorporate webmaster input in the future.

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334

Comment: Thanks. I guess 'sitelinks' are the entries below a search result (i.e. the first portion of my pictures, in the bold red border). What about the second portion of my picture though? Is that a 'sitelink' too?

Comment: I think they autogenerated too. and yes, this is `sitelink` too

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything you can do to get 'sitelinks' other than design a great, SEO friendly site.  There is nothing specific to trigger their appearance except ranking well, creating great content, and lots of visitors.  :)

Good luck with the new site!
Luke Peterson